# Publishing or subscribing data via external IP

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am running Mosquitto MQTT broker on the localhost of my PC and I want to publish or subscribe data through MQTT with Mosquitto from a remote IP (another PC). Both the PCs are connect to the same Wifi public network. I have disable the firewall of the two PCs and I am able to ping one another on command prompt. I have look up on several websites and tried editing the config file of the Mosquitto MQTT broker by adding these two lines.

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

I have started the Mosquitto broker by executing `mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v`

The following is the log appear the mosquitto start.

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v
1665133477: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1665133477: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1665133477: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1665133477: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1665133477: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

However, on the publishing PC, it prompts the error below.

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_pub -h XXX.XXX.XX.X -t Test -m "Hello World" -p 8883 -d
Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

The situation is same for subscribing. I am currently using the latest version of Mosquitto 2.0.15. Can anyone help me on this situation? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The timeout implies that the packets are never reaching the broker. I suggest you look at tools like wireshark to see what packets are actually crossing the network. Also update the question with the logs from mosquitto (to show that you are actually using the config file you think you are)